# How to determine number of legend rows from ggplot object

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given a ggplot object with a legend, how can I tell how many rows the legend has programmatically? (Rather than having to manually look at the plot.) e.g., given these two plots, how can I get `p1` to tell me its legend has 2 rows and `p2` 3 rows?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
  
p1 <- mpg %>% 
  count(drv, class) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(drv, n, fill = class)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(NULL, option = "H") +
  ggtitle("class") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")

p2 <- mpg %>% 
  count(drv, manufacturer) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(drv, n, fill = manufacturer)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(NULL, option = "H") +
  ggtitle("manufacturer") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

I've poked around the results of `ggplot_build(p1)`, but without any luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you can grab the legend grob and count the unique row/column starts. Here's a function that uses `cowplot` as a helper.

```
legend_dim <- function(plot) {
  leg <- cowplot::get_legend(plot)
  labels <- gtable::gtable_filter(leg$grobs[[1]], "label")
  c(
    length(unique(labels$layout$t)),
    length(unique(labels$layout$l))
  )
}
legend_dim(p1)
# [1] 2 4
legend_dim(p2)
# [1] 3 5
```

This returns rows/columns